# Filter dates that are in array type column Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a column **activeDt** which contains the Active Dates for each account in an array and I'd like to filter out **purchase_date** made during these Active Dates only. How can I do this in Pyspark?

```
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
|account_no|     concat_activeDt|  rcg_id|purchase_date|
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
|  91064616|[2021-09-25, 2021...|49074129|   2021-09-25|
|  91064616|[2021-09-25, 2021...|49075972|   2021-09-25|
|  91130791|[2021-06-10, 2021...|47179698|   2021-06-10|
|  91130791|[2021-06-10, 2021...|48107966|   2021-07-28|
|  91130791|[2021-06-10, 2021...|48331841|   2021-08-11|
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
```

I've tried `all_purchases.filter(col('purchase_date').isin(col('concat_activeDt')))` but am getting error due to data mismatch.

[image]

My spark version is 2.4.3

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Provide the Dataframe not as an image, and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_contains`, ref: [pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html).

Example:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {
        "account_no": 1,
        "concat_activeDT": ["2021-09-25", "2021-08-23"],
        "purchase_date": "2021-09-25",
    },
    {
        "account_no": 2,
        "concat_activeDT": ["2021-09-25", "2021-08-23"],
        "purchase_date": "2020-09-25",
    },
    {
        "account_no": 3,
        "concat_activeDT": ["2021-09-25", "2021-08-23"],
        "purchase_date": "2021-08-23",
    },
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.filter(F.array_contains(F.col("concat_activeDT"), F.col("purchase_date")))
```

Result:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------+                                 
|account_no|     concat_activeDT|purchase_date|
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
|         1|[2021-09-25, 2021...|   2021-09-25|
|         3|[2021-09-25, 2021...|   2021-08-23|
+----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

- Update

> I'm getting TypeError: Column is not iterable. I've added my schema in the question. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Since you've added the Spark version, that explains a lot.

`array_contains`, from Spark 3.0 version, can take two columns (e.g. `array_contains(col, col)`), but for Spark 2.4.3 it can't (e.g. `array_cointains(col, value)`) and that's why you get the error.

You can check it out:

- `array_contains` - [Spark 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array)
- `array_contains` - [Spark 2.4.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains)

However, there's a workaround, try this:

```py
df = df.filter(F.expr("array_contains(concat_activeDT, purchase_date)"))
```

> I've tested it with 2.4.3 and it worked, the result is the same

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm getting TypeError: Column is not iterable. I've added my schema in the question. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains(col, value)

Collection function: returns null if the array is null, true if the array contains the given value, and false

So apply ,
all_purchases.filter(F.array_contains(col('purchase_date'),col('concat_activeDt')))

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, I'm getting TypeError: Column is not iterable. Any idea why? I've added my schema in my question.